# What’s preventing my drill from going though my wall?

Tags: drywall, drill, stuck, drill-bit

I’m trying to drill holes for 3/16 screws in the walls of my room, but the drill is unable to penetrate through some parts of the wall. At first I thought I hit a nail, so I tried making another hole and got the same result, and repeat. I know it isn’t mechanical failure because I successfully went through one point in the wall. See the picture before for the one successful attempt at drilling a hole and two unsuccessful ones [image]

Fwiw I’m drilling about one foot from the ceiling. I’ve tried this at multiple points in my room, and the drill still won’t go through. What could be behind the paint and plaster?

Edit: these are the drill bits I’m using: [image] https://www.target.com/p/blue-ridge-tools-8pc-hex-shank-drill-bit-set/-/A-78262232

Comment: Brick, concrete or steel take your choice. What bit are you using?

Comment: @Solar Mike these ones that go with my Blue Ridge drill: https://www.target.com/p/blue-ridge-tools-8pc-hex-shank-drill-bit-set/-/A-78262232

Comment: You need masonry drill bit and hammer drill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A likely possibility you have to be aware of before you up the drilling stakes - you are hitting a steel protective plate that is specifically intended to warn you off of drilling a hole right there, because there are wires or pipes too close to the edge of the stud which you might drill or screw through, causing a larger problem.

Other possibilities depend on what your walls are made of (the above assumes typical wooden studs.) If it's plaster over brick, you might have hit a mortar joint on the "successful" hole. What came out when you drilled the hole? Masonry dust, or wood shavings?

Comment: Masonry Dust, I think. Definitely didn’t look like wood.

Comment: If the walls are masonry, you'll need different drill bits, and you'll dull the ones you have trying to drill masonry with them.

Comment: The drill bit that was stopped in dull/ruined. A good bit will go through sheet steel so .as commented , likely it is masonry . A friend once found out the hard way that a bit will go through steel electric conduit tubing . As @Ecnerwal  notes ; the steel plates are WARNINGS , they do not prevent drilling holes..